# Different column types on INNER JOIN

Tags: oracle, casting, case

So I got two tables that I'll reference with a INNER JOIN. In one side the column type is `Number(3, 0)` and in the other is `Varchar(150)`. Seeing that I **CAN'T** change the data types, I have to Cast it on the join. But, on the table that the column is varchar the string **always** have 3 digits like '001', '010' or even '100' and so on...

My solution is use `Case` on the join like this:

`INNER JOIN TAB1 ON TAB1.VARCHAR_COL = Cast(Case...), AS Varchar(150)`

The `Case` have to format the number to a string with the tree digits prefixed, like mentioned above.
If data comes like '1', Case have to format as '001', if comes like '10', it will change to '010'...

Help me with the `Case`.

Edit: The varchar column have some values that aren't numbers, so casting it show an error.

Comment: Why not go the other direction and CAST the varchar column to a number?

Comment: Oh, I forgot the explain that. Cause there have values that aren't numbers. So cast throws an error.

Comment: How many rows are in these tables? The danger of joining on different data types is that if there was any hope of using an index, its proabaly gone on the converted column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't seem like any need for `CASE` at all.

```
TAB1.VARCHAR_COL = TO_CHAR( TAB2.NUMBER_COL, '000' )
```

Comment: Say that TAB2.NUMBER_COL is the primary key.  Does casting this value TO_CHAR negate the indexing on this column?

Comment: @Nitax: It would prevent an index unique scan or range scan from being performed on TAB2.NUMBER_COL.  It would not necessarily prevent an index from being used in other ways such as an index full scan.  One could create a function-based index on the expression used in the join.